# Is there a registry setting I can change to disable vibrate on the Windows key?

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-surface-pro

I need to disable the Windows key on a Microsoft Surface 3 running Windows 8.1. I found a [registry tweak](https://web.archive.org/web/20150305132330/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/216893) that disables the functionality of the Windows key. In other words, the Start screen no longer pops up when I tap the Windows key. However, even with this tweak enabled, the tablet still vibrates when you tap the Windows key. Nothing happens besides this innocuous vibration, but I'd like to disable that, too. How do I disable it completely?

Comment: Sounds to me like it might be hard-wired. If that's the case, you can't do anything.

Comment: Why do you want to disable the vibration?

Comment: Because I want to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no customisation you can make at the moment for the vibration. Hopefully soon there will be a UI menu for this as it is a common request.

Comment: On Lumia Windows Phones, there is an option in the Lumia vendor specific settings to disable vibration (requires restart). I am aware it's a different OS, but the principle is the same - there is a possibility of the manufacturer adding that ability independent of Microsoft.

Comment: Darn. I was hoping there would be an easy option. I have one follow up question, and if you can answer this I'll definitely give you the bounty: I just realized that the registry tweak I mentioned does not stop users from swiping in from the right to bring up the Charms bar. I definitely need to disable that. Is there a registry setting that disables that swipe-from-right gesture?

Comment: Control Panel>Mouse>UltraNav>TouchPad Settings>Application Gestures>Edge Swipes>Deselect “Enable Edge Swipes”

Comment: Nope, that only applies to devices that have a touchpad. Touchscreen devices (like the Surface Pro 3) don't have that option in the first place. But what the hell, I'll give you the bounty anyway.

Comment: Generosity or what?! Thanks so much, I'll carry on looking for it.